# Java regex in Jenkins Text Finder to match 2 lines

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 lines in my jenkins console output and I am trying to capture them using the `Jenkins Text Finder plugin` using `java regex`
My console output looks something like this:

```
**The total percentage is:70%
Student passed the exam**
```

The `java regex` I tried is:

```
The total percentage is:([0-9]\d|\d{3,})%(\n|$)Student passed the exam
```

In the place of `(\n|$)` to pickup the next new line I tried `[\s\S]` and `(.|\n)`. But nothing is working.
Can someone help me with this.

EDIT:
The build should be unstable when either one of them is found or when both the lines were found. Meaning for `A|B|AB`

Comment: Please include the full relevant code.

Comment: Include strings that should match and strings that should not match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no code. I get the statements above (in **bold**) in the console output and I want to capture them using `Jenkins Text Finder plugin` and `unstable the build` .Even though the regex I tried is working in some websites to test `Java regex`, they are not working in the `Jenkins`

Comment: Update your question with the following: 2-3 lines of sample input, showing the breadth of data you might have, and also exactly what you are trying to extract from this data.

Comment: @MYGz I get the console output as 
`The total percentage is:70%` 
`Student passed the exam`
In 2 different lines and my build should be unstable when either of them is found or when both are found

Comment: @user6348718 Try Tim's and my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get away with the following regex:

```
^The total percentage is:[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,})?%|Student passed the exam$
```

Since the presence of *either* sentence represents a match in your console output, therefore you don't need to check for both.  So a regex with an alternation is possible here.

Here is an explanation of the pattern matching the percentage:

```
[0-9]{1,2}     one or two leading digits
(
    \.         followed by an (optional) decimal point
    [0-9]{1,}  followed by one or more digits after that (again optional)
)?
%              followed by a percent sign
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/The total percentage is:([0-9]\d|\d{3,})%\W+Student passed the exam/igm
```

`i` : for ignoring the case

`g`: matching globally

`m`: for multiline matching

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
T.*?:(\d+)%\s+.*?m
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1jtHP4/1

Comment: `\s` includes `\r` and `\n`, so `\s+` would suffice.

Comment: @Toto Thanks. Just included everything because I was not sure if anything is different on windows :) At first I did that, check `url/1`